# Open Graph image error with complex url

Tags: facebook, adobe, facebook-opengraph, scene7

I am trying to get some viral marketing with my page by alowing people to share a product with the product's image. This is a normal usecase (cliche even) however the image source is Adobe's Scene7. I have used the debugger tool facebook provides but the best they can tell me is that "The image referenced by the url of og:image tag could not be downloaded." I understand that Scene7 urls are very complex and there is a reasonable chance that this is what facebook is choking on but is there anyway around this limitation?

I cant provide an actual url (trade secrets, NDA, etc...) but the urls we are dealing with resemble `http://s7d4.scene7.com/ir/render/company/product?fmt=png&resmode=sharp2&wid=350&obj=scr&show&obj=cc&decal&src=is{company/style?$text1=H&$name1=namelong&$color1=Blue}&res=150&show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that there is some automatic encoding occurring with the url that is not working with scene 7.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL isn't publicly available (ie: I open a freshly installed browser and am able to see your link) - our scraper won't be able to see that image either. I don't think there's any work around, given the details you shared, but if a thumbnail is ok from a legal point of view (a thumbnail would end up on Facebook either way), you could use public URLs for thumbnails of the images of your products.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it seems you got the wrong idea from my question. The image is public but since it is for an unreleased product, I cant very well post it here.

Comment: Any chance you can upload a test image to a similar URL? The URL shouldn't be a problem as long as it's valid (make sure you encode it when you make the request). Providing a dummy image at a similar URL would really help tracking this down!

Comment: Any updates on this? I am running into this same problem. If you encode the URL, it doesn't work at all.